# How to solve image not found or type unknown issue in dompdf in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to create a pdf file in magento 2.

For that I'm using dompdf from [weprovide](https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf).

Pdf was generating perfectly but the image was missing. Instead of showing the image it shows an 'Image not found or type unknown'.

[image]

I've checked the HTML code that was passed to the dompdf, which has proper image link.

While I'm searching for this issue, somewhere they are mentioned to set options(`isRemoteEnabled`) for the PDF. [Link](https://blog.skunkbad.com/php/dompdf-image-not-found-or-type-unknown)

So can you help me to solve this issue.

If I want to set options in dom pdf means, how can I integrate that options in weprovide/dompdf code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by enabling the `RemoteEnabled` option.

Updated Code:

```
<?php
namespace WeProvide\Dompdf\Controller\Result;

...
use Dompdf\Dompdf as PDF;
use Dompdf\Options as Options;
...

class Dompdf extends AbstractResult
{
    public $pdf;
    public $options;
    ...

    /**
     * Dompdf constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(PDF $domPdf,Options $options)  {
        $this->pdf = $domPdf;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * Set Option
     */
    public function setRemoteOption()  {
        $this->options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
        $this->pdf->setOptions($this->options);
    }

    ....
    ...
}
?>
```

I've enabled the remote and then set the option for DOM pdf.

I hope this will helpful for someone.

Comment: How we can use this code in this file https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf/blob/master/Controller/Result/Dompdf.php